# Vim NERDTreeMenu Remapping

Tags: vim, nerdtree, colemak

I'm a Colemak keyboard layout user and I recently started to learn and use Vim.

I was able to map the arrow keys in the `normal` mode by putting custom mappings such as `noremap u k` in .vimrc (because the keys `h`, `j`, `k`, and `i` are in different places in the Colemak layout).

However, when I tried to use NERDTree, navigating through the NERDTree menu became very hard for me for I have to reach `j` and `k` key to navigate up and down (those keys are `y` and `k` in QWERTY).

Is there a way to map those two keys into other keys?

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: you should check on https://vi.stackexchange.com/ and also ask the question there if you don't find any answer...

Comment: @godot will do, thank you!

Comment: For those interested... the same question and my answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19668/7579